# State in React not changing with setState method

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function, setstate, react-state

I am trying to update my state with `setState` method in one of my functions but state doesn't somehow change. I am also using `if` statement in that function to tell the setState when to actually change state. I get back correct message in `console.log` when `if` statement is `true` but my state still doesn't change. What could cause the error?

My function and state:

```
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isregistered: false
    }
}

handleValidate = (validate) => {
    const state1 = this.state
    console.log('state1', state1)
    const validate1 = validate
    console.log('l]plik validate', validate1)
    if ( validate.length != 0){
        this.setState({
            isregistered: true
        })
        console.log('onregatud', this.state.isregistered)
   }
   else{
        console.log('mitteregatud', this.state.isregistered)
   }
}
```

Comment: Please show `render`

Comment: this function isn't connected to my UI buttons or anything. Handle validate gets called eventually under method componentDidMount and is initiated when user enters that page.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why calling react setState method doesn't mutate the state immediately?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30782948/why-calling-react-setstate-method-doesnt-mutate-the-state-immediately)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `setState()` operation is asynchronous and your `console.log()` will be executed before the `setState()` mutates the value of `isregistered` where you set it from `false` to `true` and hence you are not able to see the result.

We can solve this issue by two ways:

1. By passing a callback function to the `setState()`

   ```
    const handleValidate = (validate) => {
     const state1 = this.state
     const validate1 = validate
      if ( validate.length != 0){
        this.setState(
        { isregistered: true }, 
        () => console.log('callback fired', this.state));
      } else {
        console.log('mitteregatud', this.state.isregistered);
      }
    }
   ```
2. By using `async-await`

   ```
   async function handleValidate(validate) {
     const state1 = this.state
     const validate1 = validate
      if ( validate.length != 0){
        await this.setState({ isregistered: true})
        // More code here based on state outside callback
        console.log('onregatud', this.state.isregistered)
      } else {
        console.log('mitteregatud', this.state.isregistered)
      }
   }
   ```

   Using `async-await` is cleaner instead of using a callback in `setState()`

Answer (score 2):

It is not an error, setState is asynchronous. If you want to check the state right after a setState you need to pass a callback :

```
this.setState({myState : newState}, () => console.log(this.state.myState))
```